# Lazy queues inside ConsumerDefinition

Tags: masstransit

I have ConsumerDefinition:

```cs
public class RequestSentConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<RequestSentConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(
        IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpoint,
        IConsumerConfigurator<RequestSentConsumer> consumer)
    {
        var rabbitmq = endpoint as RabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfiguration;
        rabbitmq.Lazy = true;

        consumer.UseMessageRetry(retry => retry
            .Incremental(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }
}
```

Is there more elegant way to set queue laziness?
Maybe MT has something like `RabbitMQConsumerDefinition` or `ConsumerDefinition<RequestSentConsumer, RabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfiguration>` in any external package?

Answer (score 1):

For transport-specific configuration in a consumer definition, you should pattern match against the receive endpoint configurator, and apply the transport-specific configuration as needed.

```
protected override void ConfigureConsumer(
    IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
    IConsumerConfigurator<RequestSentConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
{
    if(endpointConfigurator is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rmq)
        rmq.Lazy = true;
}
```